# How to optimize read operation from NDB datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have the following class to store the data:

```
class AppList(ndb.Model):
    '''
    Index
      Key:              sender
    '''
    sender = ndb.StringProperty()
    texts = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
    recipients = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
    service_centers = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
    counter = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    ignore = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)

    added = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True, indexed=False)
    updated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True, indexed=False)
```

And currently it contains about 4`000 records.

When I try to read it with the following code in the cycle:

```
entries = AppList.query()
res, cur, more = entries.fetch_page(100, start_cursor=cur)
```

it fails with `OverQuotaError(The API call datastore_v3.RunQuery() required more quota than is available.)`. Free quota is 0.05 Million Ops. Looks like it happens because of multiple `repeated` properties. But the only task I have with reading all values is to assign False value to `ignore` property of each record (`entry.ignore = False`).

Is there any way to optimize reading in my case?

Comment: Have a look at appstats: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

Answer (score 1):

appstats won't help a lot as you are fetching all your entities and updating them.

A projection query won't work as you are trying to update entities.  Do the udpates in  bits and pieces over several days so you won't go over your quota or enable billing.

Writing entities with lots of properties will incur higher IOPS because you are also updating indexes.  If any properties do not need the index, set noindex=True and redeploy this will cut down you IOPS, not sure how much impact this will have.  Every property other than BlobProperty is indexed by default.

Answer (score 1):

The 50k is your [daily free quota](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Datastore) for *datastore billable ops*. Note that *datastore billable ops* are not the same as datastore API calls. See [this table](https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing#costs-for-datastore-calls) for comparison.

So querying 4k entities will result in 8k billable datastore ops. If you are close to 50k daily limit, then this API call will fail with noted error.

Comment: Thanks. But looks like in my case `entries.fetch_page(100, start_cursor=cur)` leads to more than just 200 (=100*2) billable ops. Since having 4000 entities for update I should be within the limit. Moreover, even if I go to the Datastore Viewer and list pages, after some time I am getting `OverQuotaError`.

Comment: remember its not just read that cost. Updates will cost more as all indexes for a property are updated on each put()

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to fetch the values of all properties, you can use a [projection query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#projection), for example:

```
entries = AppList.query()
res, cur, more = entries.fetch_page(100, start_cursor=cur, projection=[AppList.ignore])
```

However, the above might not solve your problem since every fetch of an entity should be just one read so there might be something else going on.